# How do I install pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am using python 3.3.2 Shell.

I would like to know how to install pygame, there is something about having to have the same version as your python compiler? There is no pygame 3.3.2, and when i import pygame there is no module named pygame. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows you can use this link to find precompiled binaries for python libraries:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

That link has a very large selection which just happens to include Pygame. Back when I was playing around with pygame (I hated it, but I digress) I downloaded this one:

pygame-1.9.2pre.win-amd64-py3.3.exe

Which is the 64 bit version of Pygame that works on Python 3.3.x.

If you're on any other OS, visit the official bitbucket for Pygame: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads